# Error no match for call to (std::vector<int>) (int&)

Tags: c++

Una función que busca un número que el usuario introduce por pantalla, lo que pasa que me dan un error el compilador que no entiendo:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

bool busqueda_recursiva(vector<int> array,int length, int x,int i);

int main (void) {

    int i=0;

    int buscado=0;
    vector<int> tabla(8);

    for (i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        tabla(i)= i+1; //inicializar vector
    }  
    cout << "cual es el elemento que desea buscar" << endl;
    cin >> buscado;

    int b=busqueda_recursiva(tabla,8,buscado, i);

    if (b){
        cout << "el elemento " << buscado << "se encuentra en el vector"<< endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << " el elemento " << buscado << " no se encuentra en el vector" << endl;
    }
}

bool busqueda_recursiva(vector<int> array ,int length,int x, int i){ //no se le pone corchetes cuando se crea 
  length = array.size(); 
  if (length==0) { 
  cout << " el vector estÃ¡ vacÃ­o " << endl;
  return 0; 
  }
  else if (x==array[i]){ //apunta al primer elemento
  return 1;
 }
 else
{
  busqueda_recursiva(array,--length,x,++i);
  cout << "el elemento es  " << x << endl;
  return 1;
  }
}
```

El error que me sale es este:

> `no match for call to (std::vector<int>) (int&)`

¿Qué puede estar causando este error?

Comment: Me he tomado la libertad de *editar* el título, para hacerlo mas claro para futuros usuarios.

Comment: Voté inicialmente para **cerrar**, pero retiré mi voto. El *mensajito* en cuestión *no está muy visto* aun, así que se podría intentar explicarlo.

Answer (score 0):

El error se encuentra en el `for` que inicializa el vector.

```
for (i=0; i<8; i++)
{
    tabla(i)= i+1; //inicializar vector <---------------- ERROR
}
```

Para añadir valores en los arrays de la clase `vector` se utiliza `push_back` como puede verse a continuación:

```
for (i=0; i<8; i++)
{
    tabla.push_back(i+1); //inicializar vector
}
```

En cambio, si lo que deseas es modificar el array, previamente tienes que haberlo inicializado  (como bien haces con `vector<int> tabla(8);` y a continuación acceder a una posición que no se encuentre vacía, por ejemplo: `tabla[posicion] = nuevoValor ;`

```
for (i=0; i<8; i++)
{
    tabla[i]= i+1; //inicializar vector
}
```

Comment: Igual, cuando crea la viariable `tabla` ( `vector< int > tabla( 8 )` ), tiene algo que ver y esta intentando hacer otra cosa. Vamos, que eso de `añadir valores a los arrays ...` es **totalmente erróneo**.

Comment: Erróneo por qué?

Comment: Porque **no los quiere añadir**, está **intentando modificar** los que ya hay: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector (Punto 4), y http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at

Comment: No puede modificar nada porque aún no le ha añadido valor alguno al vector, ahí está su problema. Y sí que quiere añadir los valores, por eso pone él mismo el comentario al lado `//inicializar vector`

Comment: Ok, entonces. Cuando lo *construye* con `vector< int >( 8 )`, está entonces creando un `vector` vacío. Tendré que revisar todos mis códigos que hacen eso para crear `vector` con **espacio preasignado** para varios elementos.

Comment: Cuando lo construye con  `vector<int> tabla(8) ;` lo que hace es reservar espacio, claro está. Pero aún él no le ha dado el **valor que quiere**, por eso él mismo más tarde escribe como comentario eso de "inicializar vector". @Dolmenes que vaya bien la revisión de código.

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo con tu *punto de vista*. Partiendo de como lo construye, lo lógico es pensar que quiere usar `[ ]` para modificar el dato situado en cierta posición. Posición **que si existe**. Supongo que todo se limita a eso, *puntos de vista**. Agradable charla, por cierto :-)

Comment: Ese constructor no reserva... **crea** 8 valores que vienen inicializados a 0. Revisa la [documentación](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector). Cito "_3) Constructs the container with count **default-inserted instances of T**. No copies are made._". Considera editar tu respuesta para no inducir a error.

Comment: creo que lo he expresado bien en la respuesta: "[...]previamente tienes que haberlo inicializado (como bien haces con `vector<int> tabla(8);`...[...]"

Comment: En ese caso sí... Pero el del push_back que casualmente está antes no. Si me pongo en la piel de alguien que está empezando no vería ahí ningún indicio de que debo modificar la construcción del vector y acabaría con 16 elementos...

Answer (score 0):

La clase `vector` no tiene sobrecargado el operador función para acceder a sus elementos, por lo que el contenido del primer bucle es erróneo:

```
for (i=0; i<8; i++)
{
    tabla(i)= i+1; //inicializar vector
//       ^^^
}
```

En su lugar debes usar, dado que ya has creado 8 elementos en el vector al construirlo, es el operador de índice `[]`

```
for (i=0; i<8; i++)
{
    tabla[i]= i+1; //inicializar vector
}
```

Pero claro, no tiene demasiado sentido que asignes un número predeterminado de posiciones y que luego hagas una iteración fija. ¿Qué sucede si luego cambias el número de elmentos a 10? o actualizas también el límite en el bucle o tendrás errores. Aquí deberías usar el método `size()` del vector:

```
for (i=0; i<tabla.size(); i++)
{
    tabla[i]= i+1; //inicializar vector
}
```

Aun sin este último cambio el programa ya compila pero... ¿qué sucede con esta llamada?

```
int b=busqueda_recursiva(tabla,8,buscado, i);
```

Si revisamos el programa veremos que `i` vale 8... vemos qué efecto tiene ese valor:

```
bool busqueda_recursiva(vector<int> array ,int length,int x, int i){
  length = array.size();
  if (length==0) { 
  cout << " el vector esta vaci­o " << endl;
  return 0; 
  }
  else if (x==array[i]){ // <<--- AQUI
  return 1;
 }
 else
   // ...
}
```

En la línea destacada con el comentario se aprecia que en la primera llamada a la función ya corres el riesgo de acceder a una posición de memoria no válida. Es el riesgo de reutilizar variables.

En mi humilde opinión el `main` debería parecerse más a esto:

```
int main () { // (1)

    //(2)
    vector<int> tabla(8);

    for (int i=0; i<8; i++) // (3)
    {
        tabla[i]= i+1; //inicializar vector
    }  
    cout << "cual es el elemento que desea buscar" << endl;
    cin >> buscado;

    bool b=busqueda_recursiva(tabla,8,buscado, 0); // (4)

    if (b){
        cout << "el elemento " << buscado << "se encuentra en el vector"<< endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << " el elemento " << buscado << " no se encuentra en el vector" << endl;
    }
}
```

Donde ...

1. En C++ las funciones que no reciben argumentos **no necesitan** `void` es redundante e innecesario.
2. En C++ (y a partir de C99 también) no es necesario declarar las variables al inicio de la función. Lo ideal es retrasar su declaración lo máximo posible.
3. Los bucles `for` admiten la declaración de variables.
4. Si la función retorna `bool` entonces almacena el valor en una variable de tipo `bool`. No tiene sentido convertir el valor a `int` y puede ser una fuente de errores.

La supuesta función recursiva también tiene varios problemas:

```
bool busqueda_recursiva(vector<int> array ,int length,int x, int i){ // (1)
  length = array.size(); // (2)
  if (length==0) { 
  cout << " el vector esta vaci­o " << endl; // (3)
  return 0; // (4)
  }
  else if (x==array[i]){ //apunta al primer elemento (5) (6)
  return 1; // (4)
 }
 else
{
  busqueda_recursiva(array,--length,x,++i);
  cout << "el elemento es  " << x << endl; // (7)
  return 1; // (4) (8)
  }
}
```

A saber:

1. Si pasas el vector por valor vas a hacer una copia del mismo en cada llamada recursiva. Esto es poco eficiente tanto en tiempo (aunque para el caso no sea un problema) como en memoria (copiar el vector un número alto de veces puede llenar la pila con suma rapidez). Es preferible pasar una referencia constante.
2. ¿De que sirve que la función reciba un argumento si sobreescribes su valor en la primera línea de la función?
3. Procura no usar caracteres no ASCII si no quieres arriesgarte a tener mensajes extraños
4. Si la función retorna un booleano lo normal es que uses `true`y `false` en vez de `1` y `0`. Recuerda que en C++ (a diferencia de C) el tipado es **fuerte** y estas cosas conviene cuidarlas.
5. ¿No compruebas el valor de `i` antes de acceder al array? ¿Y si el usuario introduce un valor inexistente? Si miras tu función únicamente retornará `false` cuando el vector esté vacío... hay situaciones que no has previsto.
6. El comentario de esa línea no solo no ayuda sino que despista completamente. No estás accediendo al primer elemento sino al que toque en esa iteración. Para tener comentarios incorrectos es mejor no tenerlos.
7. `x` es el valor que introduce el usuario. ¿Que aporta este mensaje? nada.
8. Por si no te has fijado este mensaje se va a repetir 1 vez por llamada recursiva. ¿Es necesario sacar el mismo mensaje 6 veces seguidas? yo creo que no.

Deberías repasar un poco el código.

Comment: En la parte donde explicas el recorrido a través de su tamaño tienes un error. Más concretamente aquí: `for (i=0; i<vector.size(); i++)`. Considera cambiar `i<vector.size()`por `i<tabla.size()` en tu respuesta para no dar lugar a confusión.

Comment: @MarioRodríguez Gracias por el detalle. Sin embargo te aviso que te puedes guardar la sorna. Las críticas que te he lanzado intentan ser constructivas. No conviertas esto en una pelea de gallos porque te vas a quedar solo

Comment: No entiendo por qué dices eso, yo solo intento ayudar. Pero sí que es verdad que me he visto solo desde el principio, pero me da lo mismo si al final consigo ayudar a alguien. Basta con que leas los comentarios de mi publicación de arriba para darte cuenta de lo que digo.

Comment: @MarioRodríguez yo creo que sí, en SO habrá... 10k comentarios??? Y se pueden contar con los dedos de una mano los que responden de una forma similar a la mía. Si no es como digo te pido disculpas, pero devolver así la frase mosquea